# Menu overlaps on Slider in Phone Screens

Tags: html, css

Hi my [site](http://www.135logistics.com/index.php) screen resolution is not fully displaying my slider-detail div class uniformly on phones. Below is how the site looks on phone

[image: Site view on Redmi Note 9T]

Below is the CSS code that covers the resolution on phone no idea where I'm going wrong on the slider CSS media code

```
    .slider-detail {
  padding-top: 122px; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider-detail {
      padding-top: 115px; }
```

Display ratio: 2340x1080. I have attempted to change the code on the slider class to screen and

```
(max-width: 767px)
.slider-detail {
    padding-top: 130px;
}
```

But it still not working.

Comment: We can not debug this, based on nothing but a screenshot, and a few lines of CSS, that we are not given _any_ sort of proper context for. You need to present a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-top` to .slider-detail, equal to the height of the navigation bar in that media query.